# Problem involving the computation of the following integral

Tags: complex-analysis, integration

I was solving the past exam papers and stuck on the following problem:

> Compute the integral $\displaystyle \oint_{C_1(0)} {e^{1/z}\over z} dz$,where $C_1(0)$ is the circle of radius $1$ around $z=0.$

Here,$z=0$ is a pole of order $1$ and so  Res$(f,0)=\lim_{z \to 0 } z f(z)=\lim_{z \to 0}e^{1/z}=?$ ,where $f(z)={e^{1/z}\over z}$.

Can someone point me in the right direction with some explanation?

Comment: $z=0$ is an essential singular point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $zf(z)=e^{1/z}$ also has a singularity at $0$; The laurent series of $f(z)$ is $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!}\frac{1}{z^{k+1}}=\frac{1}{z}+\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k!}\frac{1}{z^{k+1}}$. The residue is therefore $1$.

Answer (score 1):

$z=0$ is an essential singularity because of the factor $\mathrm e^{1/z}$. You can compute the integral by transforming to $w=1/z$, which yields

$$
\oint_{C_1(0)}\mathrm e^{1/z}\frac{\mathrm dz}z=\oint_{C_1(0)}\mathrm e^w\frac{\mathrm dw}w=2\pi\mathrm i\;.$$